# Why does jquery multiselect control stop working properly when dynamically filling it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui-multiselect

I have this code:

```
<select id="sState" multiple="multiple" name="sState" size="5"> 
<option value="option1">Option 1</option> 
<option value="option2">Option 2</option> 
<option value="option3">Option 3</option> 
<option value="option4">Option 4</option> 
<option value="option5">Option 5</option> 
<option value="option6">Option 6</option> 
<option value="option11">Option 11</option> 
<option value="option12">Option 12</option> 
</select>
```

Works perfectly, the CSS looks as expected.

However, when I want to fill it dynamically I have to add runat="server" to it.  The first line then must change to:

```
<select id="sState" runat="server" meta:multiple="multiple" name="sState" size="5">
```

As soon as I do that, it loses all its CSS formatting and looks like a listbox.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: do you have master page in your application? if yes, then don't apply styles based on id. Instead, use css class.

Comment: I thought the style was based off the js file?  It applies ui-multiselect styles by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs because multiselect widget appending itself to the body when partial postback. Try to removed the menu from DOM then initialize again like this:

```
<script>
    var pageRequest = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    pageRequest.add_endRequest(function () {
        $('.ui-multiselect-menu').each(function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('#sState').multiselect({
            multiple: false,
            header: false,
            noneSelectedText: false,
            selectedList: 1,
            minWidth: 170
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: When I run this, I get: 0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined